# Наследование и агрегация C#

Tags: c#, наследование

Вопрос по отношениям между классами. Есть класс `Furniture`:

```
class Furniture
{
    public Material Material { get; set; }

    public Furniture(Material mat)
    {
        Material = mat;
    }
 }
```

А также есть класс `Material`:

```
class Material
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Material(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

и класс `Steel`:

```
class Steel: Material
{
    public void WhatIsIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("it is steel");
    }

    public Steel(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

Допустим, что я создаю объекты `Steel` и `Furniture`:

```
Steel s     = new Steel("st1");
Furniture f = new Furniture(s);
f.Material.WhatIsIt(); //ошибка
```

Я подразумеваю, что создавая объект класса `Furniture`, я могу передать в него любой наследник класса `Material`, и потом могу добраться до полей и методов именно этого наследника через объект `f`, однако до них получается добраться, если сделать их `virtual` в базовом классе и переопределить в наследнике.

Что я неправильно делаю?

Comment: Что такое `tab`? `//ошибка` - что за ошибка?

Comment: `что я неправильно делаю?` - ваша проблема в том, что метод `WhatIsIt`, это по сути "что за материал?", так почему этот метод у вас в "стали", если он относится к "материалу"? Делайте его абстрактным и переопределяйте у всех наследников. По поводу самой ошибки, ну подумайте сами, у "материал" есть указанный метод? Нет, ибо это метод "стали", ну так и приводите этот тип явно (например так: `((Steel)f.Material).WhatIsIt();`, или простая проверка `if (f.Material is Steel steel) steel.WhatIsIt();`).

Comment: @aepot - зачем удалил свой ответ? Два разных варианта ответа: один с виртуальным методом, другой - с защищённым полем, - это хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить ещё такой вариант:

```
class Material
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected string Type;

    public Material(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void WhatIsIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"it is {Type}");
    }
}

class Steel : Material
{
    public Steel(string name) : base(name)
    {
        Type = "steel";
    }
}
```

В этом случае в каждом классе-наследнике нужно задать в конструкторе защищённое поле (или свойство) `Type`. А метод `WhatIsIt` переопределять не нужно.